# Incognito browsing with Safari: how to browse privately?

Tags: macos, browser, safari, private-browsing

What is the equivalent to Google Chrome incognito in Safari browser? 
In other words, how to browse privately using Safari (in my case version 7.0.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari menu (upper left, next to the Apple menu icon). About the fourth menu item down is "Private Browsing". You'll get a popup. Click "OK" to turn on private browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Safari Menu > Private Browsing...
Should remove all current session at quit - but I've never used it myself, so test it.